# Decimal value parsing in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a decimal column "TOT_AMT" defined as type "bytes" and logical type "decimal" in my avro schema.

The column is defined like below in avro schema,

```
name="TOT_AMT","type":["null",{ "type":"bytes","logicaltype":"decimal","precision":20,"scale":10}]
```

I am trying to read avro file like below

```
val rdd = sc.hadoopFile(
classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroInputFormat[MyAvroRecord]],
classOf[org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroWrapper[MyAvroRecord]],
classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable])(avropath)
```

The value appears as byte array while printing RDD. I then tried reading parsing column in a java program like

```
byte[] a = "0.3".getBytes() // 0.3 is value seen in byte array in RDD
new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(a),18)
```

However the value obtained does not match with value in avro file (I tried querying using hive). What could be problem.

Comment: Please walk through what you are expecting it to be and why you think you're expecting it.  Then perhaps we can help you understand why it's not doing what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: You clearly do not understand what is a `DECIMAL` type in SQL. So I will explain a bit of the Java implementation for Hive: `DECIMAL(p,s)` is stored as a `BigInteger` plus two integers meaning "p digits max, of which s digits after decimal separator". Then the whole stuff is serialized as `byte[]` because there is no better alternative. But there is no String involved; your `"0.3".getBytes()` attempt is off the mark.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter : So how can I get the original decimal value back?

Comment: Can you map a Hive table successfully on your AVRO files ? If yes, then you should be able to map a DataFrame -- using the Hive descriptor. And maybe using the raw file + descriptor (never tried that myself, but look at the DF documentation).